# negative integers in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to make a query in a postgresql database.
I need to multiply by -1 the id before the query.

```
def getRelation(request,id):
    #id = id * -1
    #osmObject = get_object_or_404(PlanetOsmPolygon,osm_id=int(id))
    return HttpResponse(id)
    #return HttpResponse(osmObject.way.geojson)
```

This is my view.
This code works, however, if I uncomment the multiply, there is nothing in my browser. I can't see my negative id. Where is the mistake?

If I uncomment `get_object_404`, I have a :

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

That's why I tried `int()`.

This problem seems to be very simple and I don't understand why. I begin in django.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parameters captured from urls (your `id` here) are injected as strings

you need to coerce it *before* you start working with it

something like

```
def getRelation(request, id):
    id = int(id)
    # the rest of your view
```

*update* (re: blank string)

python lets you repeat strings by overloading the multiplication operator

```
>>> "foo" * 3
'foofoofoo'
```

when you try to multiply a string (containing your id, but as a string) with `-1`, you get "-1 copies", which returns an empty string

```
>>> "foo" * -1
''
```

or in your case:

```
>>> "12" * -1
''
>>> int("12") * -1
-12
```

Comment: Thanks for all these explications.